# Get User's Time Zone using PnPJs

Tags: sharepoint-online, user-profile, spfx-webparts, pnp, pnpjs

We are trying to retreive current user's profile Time Zone `SPS-TimeZone` from a SharePoint Framework webpart, but we are faicing an error (see below). Does anyone know about the best/most effecient way of getting current user's time zone from a user profile? Maybe without an extra request?  Unfortunately, getting  time zones from JavaScript by using `new DateTime` is not an option in our case.

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";

async function Main(){
  const timeZone = await 
  sp.profiles.myProperties.select("SPS%2dTimeZone").get()
  console.log(timeZone);
}
Main();
```

Error:

> Uncaught (in promise) Error: Error making HttpClient request in queryable [400]  ::> {"odata.error":{"code":"-1, Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.InvalidClientQueryException","message":{"lang":"en-US","value":"The expression \"SPS-TimeZone\" is not valid."}}}
>       at new HttpRequestError (sp.es5.umd.bundle.js:1831)
>       at sp.es5.umd.bundle.js:1840

When we get all user profiperties, then `SPS-TimeZone` is there

```
import { sp } from "@pnp/sp";

async function Main(){
  const timeZone = await sp.profiles.myProperties.get()
  console.log(timeZone)
}
Main();
```

In theory, we could get all user's properties and then select the one we want, but getting all properties takes about 900ms whereas getting a single one is only 200ms. We think waiting for 1 seconds just to get user's time zone is too expensive.

[image]

**Using this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext**

We were also thinking about using legacypageContext, but I've read that this object's properties might change in the future and we are encouraged to make an API call instead. Can someone comment on this, please? Is it really not safe to use legacyPageContext?

```
this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext.webTimeZoneData
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, correct me if I'm wrong. 
Even though we are not supposed to use `legacyPageContext`, there is still a way to get to the page contenxt via `this.context.pageContext`. It's not exactly the same as the good old `_spContextInfo`, but it is supposed to have most if not all properties. For example:

Istead of...

```
this.context.pageContext.legacyPageContext.userTimeZoneData
```

We need to access the user's time zone the following way:

```
const user:any = this.context.pageContext.user;
console.log("user.timeZoneInfo:", user.timeZoneInfo);
```

Notice that I have to cast `this.context.pageContext.user` to `any`. This is because `timeZoneInfo` property contains the value even though there is no property in the interface. Strange, but OK...